# regular expression a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I Need a regular expression which will convert the following object:

```
"{:email=>[\"has already been taken\"], :name=>[\"has already been taken\"]}"
```

to

```
Email has already been taken, Name has already been taken
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ str = "{:email=>[\"has already been taken\"], :name=>[\"has already been taken\"]}"
▶ eval(str).map { |k, v| [k.capitalize, v].join(' ') }.join(', ')
#⇒ "Email has already been taken, Name has already been taken"
```

With `scan`:

```
▶ str.scan(/:(\w+)=>\["(.*?)"\]/).map do |k, v|
▷   [k.capitalize, v].join(' ')
▷ end.join(', ')
#⇒ "Email has already been taken, Name has already been taken"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that:

```
def convert(str)
  arr = [' '].concat str.chars
  str.gsub(/./) do |c|
    case arr.shift
    when ':' then c.upcase
    when '=' then ' '
    else c =~ /[,\sa-zA-Z]/ ? c : ''
    end
  end
end

str = '{:email=>[\"has already been taken\"], :name=>[\"has already been taken\"]}'

convert str
  #=> "Email has already been taken, Name has already been taken"
```